# How can I get a IPython NotebookApp to be started and still manage it from outside of a browser?

Tags: ipython, tornado, jupyter-notebook

It is possible to start a notebook app within an ipython console by

```
from IPython.html import notebookapp
nbapp = notebookapp.NotebookApp()
nbapp.initialize()
nbapp.start()
```

This will simply open a browser with a dashboard from which is possible to create/delete and start/shutdown notebooks. However nbapp.start() hooks up to tornado http server and it is not possible to use the instance nbapp to manage the notebooks from the console. 
Some level of management can be done before executing the method nbapp.start(), but I couldn't find a way to start a proper notebook(linked to a new ipython kernel) page which can be read and edited from a web browser.

By taking a look at the start method in NotebookApp class, it seems that all the magic is done by the following method call

```
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This is the link for what I am refering to.
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/html/notebookapp.py#L824

ioloop is imported at the beginning of the file and I didn't quite understand what this actually do.

```
# Install the pyzmq ioloop. This has to be done before anything else from
# tornado is imported.
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
ioloop.install()
```

I was wondering if there was a way to start the server just the way it is working now, and send requests to it, as it works on a click of a mouse on the dashboard.
Or even better, have full access to the nbapp instance to create and start notebooks in the server.

Hope someone can help me with that, I would love to better understand how the ipython notebook work at the back stage.

Cheers

Comment: The server is controlled by a REST API, so probably the easiest way would be to start another console and write a CLI that spoke to the server API.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that is some of the ideas I have in mind. I am working on a different project now. I will try to implement something later and if I am successful will post something here. Any new ideas or simple examples would be really helpful. Cheers